# Send call open event from the event ItemChanged of a DataWindow

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datawindow, ancestor

I try to send for the Open event of the window from the event ItemChanged a DataWindow using the: `SUPER :: EVENT OPEN ()` in addition to the open event contains "script ancestor" I also need to run; itself need to restart the window from the event ItemChanged of a DataWindow.

I hope your help.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A few things jump out from your question.

`SUPER::EVENT OPEN()` will try to call the Open event of the *DataWindow* if called from the ItemChanged, not the *Window*.

I'm not 100% sure of this, but I'm pretty sure I've run into problems trying to call the ancestor of one script from a completely different script. I can't point to documentation; I'll have to just chalk it up to experienced suspicion.

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but if you want to call the Open of the window (and I'll suggest otherwise below), and if the window's Open script either extends the ancestor script or explicitly calls the ancestor script (as above), explicitly calling the ancestor script is unnecessary, and strikes me as potentially undesirable. Just call the Open script of the window you're writing.

This will depend entirely on your code, but of the dozens of systems I've had to maintain, I'd **never** assume that running the Open event of a Window would "restart" the window. Most systems I've worked on, that would just create an unexpected mix of previous and new states. Additionally, even if I coded this from scratch to work perfectly in this way, I'd assume that the next guy that came along to maintain my code (after I won the lottery and retired to a small South Pacific island) would code in a way that made perfect sense to him based on other systems he worked on, but would screw up my assumptions. If I needed to "restart" the window, I would either:

- close the window and post an Open() (the *function*, not the event) of the window again
- create a ue_ResetWindow event, hopefully coding so that the Open could use it as well, that made it obvious that anything added to the window needed to be maintained in this script as well

(Of the two, the latter would be far better user experience and coding, IMHO.)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: It's a bad idea in general to call built-in events from your code, with the exception of using the SUPER:: keyword to call an ancestor script. Even that is suspect, because it may be circumventing framework code. I mark every event script I find that overrides the ancestor with `// OVERRIDES ANCESTOR` at the top. Code that calls e.g. `cb_1.clicked` doesn't pass peer review here.

Comment: Hugh makes a good point, that is usually one of my hobby-horses, but I neglected it this time. Today, you may think that you need to invoke all the logic that's in the Open event, but next month, someone else is going to come along with something that needs to be exclusively called in one case or the other, and the more junior of staff will jump through hoops (e.g. setting flags) to keep the code there. Break it out now, call it from both places, save yourself in the long term.